# Unable to autoscroll JScrollPane when dragging a JList item

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jscrollpane, jlist

I have many JLists(each within its own JScrollPane) arranged horizontally on a JPanel. This JPanel is in turn added to a JScrollPane of its own. I have set a TransferHandler on each JList which handles the drag and drop of list items via the methods canImport, importData, createTransferable, exportDone and getSourceActions(Only valid action is MOVE).

I can drag and drop list items from 1 JList to another. However, because I am unable to see all JLists at once, if I want to drag list item(s) from a JList to another that is not visible, scrolling horizontally is required. Thus, the problem arises when I am unable to scroll the scrollpane while dragging the chosen list items.

I have tried using MouseMotionListener mouseDragged method to no avail as no mouseDragged events are sent when I am dragging the list item.

Comment: Provide at least a screenshot of the panel and point out which scroll exactly doesn't work. Code example of what you have tried to do to enable the scrolling would also be helpful. I can imagine at least three or four different cases for your description.